# Serializing a subsonic class to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

As the question goes , how do i go about serializing a subsonic class to JSON. While i can manually create the JSON object i need some way to do it automatically.

Any recommendations would be awesome as i don't really want to do this manually.
Could you also please recommend a could Library to help with the JSON serialization.

BTW i am doing all of this in ASP.Net 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the JavaScriptSerializer class? It will create a JSON version of a .NET type, including any public properties and a __type property so that the object can be reconstructed/deserialized when necessary.

Also not that WebMethods return JSON, which makes it incredibly convenient to send objects back and forth from AJAX to the server.

**EDIT**: added some example code in response to OP's comments.

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

The method GetDate() above is a webmethod. Note that it has the **[WebMethod]** attribute applied, and that it is **static**. Note that the page in which a webMethod resides will call it's **page_load()** method each time you call one of its webMethods. Code your pages accordingly.

To call a webMethod from JavaScript, you can use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.

        alert('Received from webmethod: '+result.d);
      }
    });
```

The example webMethod here returns a string, but just about any object type can be returned instead. There are many good references in SO, as well as around the .NET, on using webMethods.

**If you don't need the power of a webMethod** and, instead, wish only to serialize an object into JSON, just use the JSON serializer:

```
public string MyClassToJson(MyClass mc)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    string serializedObject = serializer.Serialize(mc);

    return serializedObject;
}
```

Comment: What WebMethods are you referring to as that may help me as well

Comment: A WebMethod is a static method declared inside of an ASP.NET page that is intended to be called from client-side script. It's similar to a method in a web service (.asmx), but is declared inside of a regular .aspx page, instead. 
I've entered some additional references in my reply above.

Comment: Thanks dude awesome info , i found it alot easier to do using JSON.Net , all it takes is the following 
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass);
I havent tested your way of doing it but will mark it as complete any way

Answer (score 0):

I would check out either [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx):

> The Json.NET library makes working
>   with JavaScript and JSON formatted
>   data in .NET simple. Quickly read and
>   write JSON using the JsonReader and
>   JsonWriter or serialize your .NET
>   objects with a single method call
>   using the JsonSerializer.

or [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx):

> Use the `DataContractJsonSerializer`
>   class to serialize instances of a type
>   into a JSON document and to
>   deserialize a JSON document into an
>   instance of a type. For example, you
>   can create a type named `Person` with
>   properties that contain essential
>   data, such as a name and address. You
>   can then create and manipulate an
>   instance of the `Person` class and
>   write all of its property values in a
>   JSON document for later retrieval.
>   This JSON document can later be
>   deserialized into the `Person` class
>   or another class with an equivalent
>   data contract.

Comment: I have looked at Json.Net but its still a very manual process where i have to manually create my Json objects. I will have a loot at the DataContractJsonSerializer and see if it works but it seems what its what i am looking for.